# Check a number as prime or not by divisibility with prime numbers less than it and storing that in an array if proved to be prime in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

**PROBLEM**

How to make an array which could increase its length when needed during run-time.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int *arr;
    int count=0,i=3,j,n;
    arr=(int*)malloc(count+1*sizeof(int)); /*here i set array size to 1*/
    arr[count++]=2; /*stored 2 as array first element*/
    printf("Find all prime numbers upto :: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); /*n is the number up to which prime numbers are required*/
    here:
    {
        while(i<=n) /*start with i=3*/
        {
            j=0;
            while(arr[j]<=sqrt(i)) /*till array element value less than or equal to root of number under checking*/
            {
                if(i%arr[j]!=0) /*if remainder is not zero check*/
                    j++;        /*divisibility with next array element*/              
                else
                {
                    i++;          /*if remainder is zero then*/
                    goto here;    /*start checking for another number*/
                }
            }
            printf("%d, ",arr[count-1]); /*printing the number which was proved to be prime last time*/
            arr=(int *)realloc(arr,(count+1)*sizeof(int)); /*increasing array size by 1*/
            arr[count++]=i; /*newly proved prime is stored as next array element*/
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d, ",arr[count-1]); /*print last number proved to be prime*/
    }
}
```

**THANK YOU! STACKOVERFLOW**

That was my first question in C here and this platform helped me a lot in solving my problem, understanding new concepts and having the proper code.

Comment: Not working? You must be more specific for anybody to help you on that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we address *specific* questions here.  "Help me understand and fix the errors" is not the kind of thing we do.

Comment: What do you mean by the tag - shortest?

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` will not work. `scanf` needs the address of a variable.

Comment: thanks @JensGustedt for pointing `scanf` error.

Comment: @JensGustedt actually i want to know how to initialize array which would increase its length as a new element is added during the program and how to write the statement to determine whether the array has no element next that i tried to express with the help of NULL.

Comment: C has no such data type that would extend automatically.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ok.. any solution to such situation?

Comment: Sure, you'd have to do that manually by using `malloc/realloc`. But in your case you shouldn't even do that. A `static` array  of 1Mio elements could serve you for a long time.

Comment: 1.  Use `malloc` to dynamically allocate a simulated array of, say, 100 elements.  Keep track of the current sze of the array (initially 100), and the number of sells you have used (initially 0, incremented each time you store a new prime number).  2. Every time you're about to store a new number in the array, check to see that there's room.  3. If not, call `realloc` to reallocate the simulated array bigger.  (At that point you will also increase the variable that tracks the size of the array.)

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you very much.. i am happy that you understand my problem but i am just a beginner and started learning C just a few days before.. so please if could give me a solution with illustration or any reference to learn about what you want to say.

Comment: @RISHUANAND There are lots of examples out there, it shouldn't be too hard to find some.  (A web search on "realloc example" would be a good start.)  Here are two pages of interested from the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html) and [my C Programming tutorial](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx11c.html).

Comment: I have updated the code and my problem... please look at it and reply me as soon as possible... @SteveSummit

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya sir actually i thought if this logic could be converted into a proper code then it would be one of the efficient and quicker way of printing prime numbers in C..

Comment: I have updated the code and my problem... please look at it and reply me as soon as possible... @JensGustedt

Comment: Your use of `count` is inconsistent.  It's best if it's the count of elements currently in the array.  So change it to `arr[count++]=2`, and `while(j<count)`, and `arr[count++]=i`, and `for(j=0;j<count;j++)` at the end.  Also you forgot `sizeof(int)` in the `realloc` call; make it `arr=realloc(arr,(count+1)*sizeof(int));`.  Also get rid of `count=count+1`.

Comment: Also if you want it to print primes up to `n` (as opposed to the
first `n` primes), you could change it to `while(arr[count-1]<=n)`,
although that prints one too far.

Comment: Also please don't say "please reply me as soon as possible" when
you're relying on volunteers for help!  (When we reply to you is,
by definition, as soon as it is possible to do so, so you don't
need to ask.)

Comment: @SteveSummit first `n` prime numbers can be printed just by changing the condition to `while(count<n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Logic is correct, but it's not so efficient, and also the code isn't correct.

I did some change to your code and now it works, and the changes were as follows:

```
scanf("%d",n) ==> scanf("%d",&n);
while (j == count) ==> while (j <= count)
```

and now it work!!

Comment: thank you very much! now its working.. but still there is an issue with initializing the array.. because i don't know by how much to initialize it.

Comment: In C if you don't know how much elements will have in your array set it to a number which is big enough like 10^5.
But if you can use C++ then what you need is pre-defined in C++ std::vector.

Comment: as i could mention `int arr[large value to skip the problem]` but i want to know if there is much better solution to this situation in C.

Comment: and as you talked about the efficiency of the program.. i think its much better and quicker approach than any other method of printing prime numbers as it saves many operations of divisibility.

Comment: For both of your comments before a way to solve your problem would be using Sieve of Eratosthenes..
The basic idea is to get a boolean array (It could be up to 10^8 :D )..
The array will be cleared before start, and you start running from 2 mark all multiples of 2 in the boolean array by 1 and go to the next element in the array which isn't marked (i.e. 3) then repeat the process before..
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: thanks a lot!!! i am very much interested in maths also... and you found me a great solution... thanks again<3

Comment: i have updated my code and facing a new problem.. please look at it and reply me as soon as possible..